# Get body of Bad Request httpURLConnection.getInputStream()

Tags: httpurlconnection

I've been working on a portlet that calls Rest API. When the API is called and the requested data doesn't exist, it returns an appropriate error message in JSON format (with Bad request http code - 400), and if the id exists, it returns the requested data in json (with code 200).

How can I get the body of response (that contains error description) because invoking `httpConn.getInputStream()` method throws exception in case the response is bad request error.

Code:

```
HttpURLConnection httpConn = null;
URL url = new URL("http://192.168.1.20/personinfo.html?id=30");   
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) connection;
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
BufferedReader br = null;
if (!(httpConn.getResponseCode() == 400)) {
     br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((httpConn.getInputStream())));
     String output;
     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
     System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
     while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) 
          builder.append(output);
     return builder.toString();
}else
   here should catch the error message. :)
```

Comment: In which way do you deserialize the JSON objects? Do you use `org.json` or Jackson or Gson?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

In case of non-successful response codes, you have to read the body with [HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream%28%29).

Comment: That is so true! Everybody says HttpURLConnection does not support it but it indeed does with `getErrorStream()`.

Comment: In my case HttpURLConnection.getErrorStream() also returns null and when I do HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(), it thoriws IOException !!
Can you help me to figure out what could be the case ?
I have exactly the same code that is mentioned above in question. I am sending post request.

Comment: What is your response-code? Can you simulate the request to the server with some REST-tool (postman) or cURL? Maybe it'd be better to ask a new question then.

Comment: @shkschneider
Who was this "Everybody" and why did he brazenly lie to you? :)

Answer (score 16):

you can get body of Bad Request in **HttpURLConnection** using this code :

```
InputStream errorstream = connection.getErrorStream();

String response = "";

String line;

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(errorstream));

while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    response += line;
}

Log.d("body of Bad Request HttpURLConnection", "Response: " + response);
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Everyone keeps saying use `getErrorStream()`, but completely forgot that I had to "read" the **_error stream_** like the **_input stream_** - can be very tricky for the newbies.

Answer (score 1):

**Use Apache Httpclient:**

```
        String url = "http://192.168.1.6:7003/life/lifews/getFirstInstallment.html?rootPolicyNo=1392/2126/2/106/9995/1904&token=1984";
        HttpClient client = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);

        // add request header
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
        System.out.println("Response Code : " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent()));
        StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
        String line = "";
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null)
            result.append(line);
        System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: This is more of an alternative answer because it doesn't use `HttpURLConnection` like OP is using.