# HttpURLConnection: how to read payload of 400 response

Tags: java, json, httpurlconnection, ioexception, payload

I use the following code to send a JSON request to my web service, and, for a bad request I return a 400 message code along with a detailed JSON error response in the payload.

I do not understand how I could possibly retrieve this payload on the client side when using `HttpURLConnection`, as it immediately throws an `IOException` and the connection's `InputStream` is `null`.

```
HttpURLConnection connection = this.connect(url);
connection.setRequestMethod(method);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(jsonMessage);
InputStream is = null;
try {
    is = connection.getInputStream(); // IOException is thrown, how can I still get payload??
} catch (Exception e) {
} 
String response = getStringFromInputStream(is);
```

Also tried to use `getErrorStream()`, but this was containing Apache Tomcat's default error page rather than the payload I can see when, e.g. I use a visual REST API client.

Comment: sorry but your .... question doesnt make much sense - you're talking about server-to-client conversations via HTTP and yet you show code which apparently describes client-to-server conversations

Comment: Here's a SO community wiki about HttpURLConnection that might be helpful:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793150/how-to-use-java-net-urlconnection-to-fire-and-handle-http-requests

Comment: getErrorStream() returned you what was really returned. If that's not what you intended to return your Tomcat configuration is wrong somewhere.

Comment: @EJP, thanks this is what i thought too, but a visual JSON client actually returns the correct payload, as well as a client i wrote with appache http package:

    `Status
    400 Bad Request Loading time: 25
    Response headers 
    Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1 
    Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 
    Transfer-Encoding: chunked 
    Date: Sat, 12 Jul 2014 11:30:57 GMT 
    Connection: close
    Response
    {
       error: "Your email address is already registered! "
       status: "BAD_REQUEST"
       fields: [1]
        0:  "email"
       -
     }`

Comment: Whatever the server returned is what you get. Clearly this is different in different cases. The client end has nothing to do with it. You're looking in the wrong place.

Comment: I have found numerous threads whereby HTTPUrlConnection simply doesnt transfer the standard payload if the status code is an error message, e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526082/get-body-of-bad-request-httpurlconnection-getinputstream, also please refer to blog in case http://www.tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection Either way, thank you all for the help. I ended up using the much more powerfull Apache package (without any server side changes ;-))

Comment: You haven't found any such thing. At least your cited thread doesn't say so. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21529527/207421) provides the solution, which I already gave you above.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found numerous threads which state that HTTPUrlConnection simply does not transfer the standard payload if the status code is an error message, e.g. [stackoverflow.com/questions/21526082/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21526082/)…, also please refer to this blog in case [tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection](http://tbray.org/ongoing/When/201x/2012/01/17/HttpURLConnection).

I ended up using the much more powerful Apache package.

Comment: You haven't found any such thing. At least your cited thread doesn't say so. [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21529527/207421) provides the solution.

Comment: When using `java.net.HttpURLConnection` and you get an error response code, then you cannot read the body with `getInputStream()`
In this case you have to read the body with `getErrorStream()`

Comment: @Teixi response should be the accepted one